# How to use url_for() to pass path and query data to a route using FastAPI and Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I would like to call a FastAPI route from within Jinja2 template, and pass both *path* and *query* data (parameters) to that route. I tried in the Jinja2 template something like this:

```
{{ url_for('function1', uustr=data.uustr, interval=1) }}
```

Here is the FastAPI route that I would like to call (syntax has been simplified for demo purposes):

```
@app.get("/updates/data/{uustr}",response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def function1(request: Request, uustr:str, interval:int):

  return"""
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ uustr }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ interval }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

I get this error:

```
raise ValueError('context must include a "request" key') 
ValueError: context must include a "request" key
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the FastAPI documentation for jinja templates? Looks like they do it in a very different way to yours: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#using-jinja2templates

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and you are right. The usage there is different. In the documentation they use `url_for()` for locating a folder. I want to use it to call a route. At least in flask something like this is possible. I hope also in fastapi

Answer (score 5):

This is not FastAPI's issue, but rather [Starlette's](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/323#issuecomment-506837279) issue (i.e., `request.url_for()` receives `path` parameters, **not** `query` parameters). So, nspired by [#560](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/560#issuecomment-769622920) and [#1385](https://github.com/encode/starlette/pull/1385), I have created the following working example for calling FastAPI routes from within Jinja2 templates, and passing `query` params (alone or along with `path` params as well).

Please note that this is a feature that is probably about to be introduced into the next version of Starlette [#1385](https://github.com/encode/starlette/pull/1385). Thus, best to use that one, when it is out.

**app.py**

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
import urllib

app = FastAPI()

 
class CustomURLProcessor:
    def __init__(self):  
        self.path = "" 
        self.request = None

    def url_for(self, request: Request, name: str, **params: str):
        self.path = request.url_for(name, **params)
        self.request = request
        return self
    
    def include_query_params(self, **params: str):
        parsed = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path))
        parsed[4] = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        return urllib.parse.urlunparse(parsed)


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')
templates.env.globals['CustomURLProcessor'] = CustomURLProcessor


@app.get('/updates/page/{page_no}/item/{item_id}')
def updates(request: Request, page_no: int, item_id: int, user: str, msg: str):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("item.html", {"request": request, "page_no": page_no, "item_id":item_id, "user": user, "msg": msg})


@app.get('/updates_query_only')
def updates_query_only(request: Request, user: str, msg: str):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("item.html", {"request": request, "user": user, "msg": msg})

@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html",  {"request": request})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, debug=True)
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {% set cu = CustomURLProcessor() %}
            {% set _url = cu.url_for(request, 'updates', page_no=5, item_id=3).include_query_params(user='foo', msg='bar') %}
            <!-- if only query params required, use as follows: -->
            {# {% set _url = cu.url_for(request, 'updates_query_only').include_query_params(user='foo', msg='bar') %} #}
            
            <iframe src="{{ _url }}" width = 300 height = 300 style= "border: none;"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

templates/**item.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Page No {{ page_no }}</h1>
        <h2>Item {{ item_id }}</h2>
        <h3>{{ user }}</h3>
        <h4>{{ msg }}</h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Update 1 - Including query parameters

You can now use Starlette's [`starlette.datastructures.URL`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L21), which provides a method to [`include_query_params`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L141). Example below:

In **app.py** import the `URL` class and make it accessible from Jinja2 templates:

```py
from starlette.datastructures import URL

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
templates.env.globals['URL'] = URL
```

In templates/**item.html** use as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <iframe src="{{ URL(url_for('updates', page_no=5, item_id=3)).include_query_params(user='foo', msg='bar') }}" width = 300 height = 300 style= "border: none;"></iframe>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Update 2 - Including query parameters

The [`request.url_for()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/requests.py#L174) function now returns a [`starlette.datastructures.URL`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L21) object. Hence, you could simply add query parameters to the URL as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <iframe src="{{ url_for('updates', page_no=5, item_id=3).include_query_params(user='foo', msg='bar') }}" width = 300 height = 300 style= "border: none;"></iframe>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that Starlette/FastAPI's `url_for()` returns a `starlette.datastructures.URL`, so you can do: `url_for('route_name', path_param=1).include_query_params(extra=2)` without wrapping the call in URL.

Comment: @Ross In Starlette's earlier versions, that wasn't the case. Thank you for letting me know. The answer has been updated.

Answer (score -1):

I found a very easy solution without using `url_for()`

In case someone coming from flask world has a similar problem here my solution:
I created a simple HTML button in my jinja2 template:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">pass data to route</button>
```

and I created a very simple javascript function for passing data to route:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.location.href = "/updates/data/{{data.uustr}}?interval=2";
}
</script>
```

that's it.