# How to redirect to dynamic URL inside a FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, redirect, jinja2, fastapi

I'm doing a feature where the user on their profile page makes changes (not related to the user model). Everything is implemented through static `HTML` templates. I need the user to click on the button and return to the same page (i.e., their profile page) after processing the request.

**Html template**

```
<td><a href="{{ url_for('decline_event_invite', pk=invite.id) }}" class="btn blue lighten-2">Accept</a></td>
```

**endpoints.py**

```
@router.get('/invite/{pk}/decline')
async def decline_event_invite(
        request: Request,
        pk: int,
        user_id: str = Depends(get_current_user),
        service: InviteService = Depends(),
):
    await service.invite_decline(pk)
    ...
    --> here I want redirect to user profile page 
    return RedirectResponse('DYNAMIC URL WITH ARGS')
```

**profile.py**

```
@router.get('/{pk}')
async def user_profile(
        request: Request,
        pk: int,
        service: UserService = Depends()
):
    user = await service.get_user_info(pk)
    events_invites = await service.get_user_events_invite_list(pk)
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        'profile.html',
        context=
        {
            'request': request,
            'user': user,
            'events_invites': events_invites,
        }
    )
```

But I can't find anywhere how to do a **redirect** similar to the logic that applies to templates. For example:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('user_profile', pk=pk) }}">Sender</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `url_for()` function and pass the (`**kwargs`) path parameters.

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
import urllib
from fastapi import APIRouter

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get('/invite/{pk}/decline')
def decline_event_invite(request: Request, pk: int):
    redirect_url = request.url_for('user_profile', **{ 'pk' : pk})
    return RedirectResponse(redirect_url)    

@app.get('/{pk}')
def user_profile(request: Request, pk: int):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("profile.html", {"request": request, "pk": pk})
```

### To add query params

In case you had to pass query params as well, you could use the following code (make sure to `import urllib`). Alternatively, you could use the `CustomURLProcessor`, as described in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633588/17865804) answer (which pretty much follows the same approach).

If the endpoint expected query params, for example:

```py
@router.get('/{pk}')
def user_profile(request: Request, pk: int, message: str):
    pass
```

you could use:

```py
redirect_url = request.url_for('user_profile', pk=pk)
parsed = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(redirect_url))
parsed[4] = urllib.parse.urlencode({**{ 'message' : "Success!"}})
redirect_url = urllib.parse.urlunparse(parsed)
```

or even use:

```py
message = 'Success!'
redirect_url = request.url_for('user_profile', pk=pk) + f'?message={message}'
```

### Update 1 - About including query parameters

Another solution would be to use Starlette's [`starlette.datastructures.URL`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L21), which now provides a method to [`include_query_params`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L141). Example:

```py
from starlette.datastructures import URL

redirect_url = URL(request.url_for('user_profile', pk=pk)).include_query_params(message="Success!")
```

### Update 2 - About including query parameters

The [`request.url_for()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/requests.py#L174) function now returns a [`starlette.datastructures.URL`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L21) object. Hence, you could simply use include query parameters as follows:

```py
redirect_url = request.url_for('user_profile', pk=pk).include_query_params(message="Success!")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting. I will try to compare the two options