# How to use HX-Redirect in HTMX frontend using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, htmx, starlette

I'm trying to redirect on the frontend after a login. I make a request from my htmx frontend like this

```html
<form hx-post="/authenticate" hx-target= "#success" id="login-form">

  <div id="success" class="mb-2"></div>

 </div>
.......input fields and submit button.....
</form>
```

My authenticate endpoint looks like this

```py
@router.post("/authenticate", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def authenticate(request: Request, response: Response, email: str = Form(), password: str = Form()):

    ..........
    #auth logic#
    ............
    response.headers["HX-Redirect"] = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
    data = {
        "success": "Logged in successfully"
    }
    return web_config.templates.TemplateResponse("auth_success.html", {"request": request, "data": data})
```

I know the code works because `auth_success.html` is successfully swapped on the frontend but what I expect to happen next is for the browser to redirect to the homepage(http://127.0.0.1:8000/), but it doesn't happen.

My CORS settings are all correct

```
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
        expose_headers=["*"],
```

NOTE: Using `RedirectResponse` wouldn't work because of how HTMX(not HTML) works. It'll only call the endpoint and swap it's response into `<div id="success"></div>` which is not a redirect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect the user back to the home page using FastAPI, after submitting an HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690454/how-to-redirect-the-user-back-to-the-home-page-using-fastapi-after-submitting-a)

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70658754/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804).

Comment: @Chris, i already tried redirectresponse. It wouldn't work for my case specifically because of how htmx(not just hmtl) works. What this will do is to swap the result of redirectresponse(the template response) into the div with id "success" in my HTML markup and that's not what I want.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. your last comment about assingning the the template response object to the response object was actually what worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the redirection not taking place is due to the way you attempt adding the `HX-Redirect` header to the response. You are currently adding it to the `Response` object; however, since you are returning a `TemplateResponse` instead, the header is **not** added to the response you are actually returning. Hence, you should instead add the `HX-Redirect` header to the `TemplateResponse`, similar to the example below:

```py
@router.post('/authenticate', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def authenticate(request: Request, email: str = Form(), password: str = Form()):
    # ...
    
    data = {'msg': 'Logged in successfully'}
    response = templates.TemplateResponse('auth_success.html', {'request': request, 'data': data})
    response.headers['HX-Redirect'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    return response
```