# Send query params from Jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi, starlette

I can't figure out if it's possible to pass query parameters from a static html page to a view for processing. I have now implemented the functionality I need using path parameters. I want to do the same, but with query parameters

**main.py**

```
from helpers.utils import CustomURLProcessor

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
templates.env.globals['CustomURLProcessor'] = CustomURLProcessor
```

**events.py**

```
router = APIRouter()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@router.post('/invite/{event_invite}/sender/{sender}')
async def decline_event_invite(
        request: Request,
        event_invite: int,
        sender: int,
):
    #logic
```

**routes.py**

```
api_router.include_router(events.router, prefix="/event")
```

html

```
{{ url_for('decline_event_invite',  event_invite=invite.id, sender=invite.sender) }}
```

It's works with  `"POST /event/invite/15/sender/3 HTTP/1.1"` as a sample

Try with query params

```
@router.post('/invite')
async def decline_event_invite(
        request: Request,
        event_invite: Optional[str] = None,
        sender: Optional[str] = None,
):
    # logic
```

And get

```
    raise NoMatchFound()
starlette.routing.NoMatchFound
```

html template without any change

Can I pass query parameters from the template to the fastapi logic to processing this url `/event/?event_invite=15&sender=3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Starlette's issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/323#issuecomment-506837279) (i.e., `url_for()` receives `path` parameters, **not** `query` parameters). What you could do is to create a custom URL processor (as shown below) and use it to pass `path` and/or `query` parameters as well.

```py
import urllib

class CustomURLProcessor:
    def __init__(self):  
        self.path = "" 
        self.request = None

    def url_for(self, request: Request, name: str, **params: str):
        self.path = request.url_for(name, **params)
        self.request = request
        return self
    
    def include_query_params(self, **params: str):
        parsed = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path))
        parsed[4] = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        return urllib.parse.urlunparse(parsed)
```

Remember to add the `CustomURLProcessor` class to the templates' global environment:

```
templates.env.globals['CustomURLProcessor'] = CustomURLProcessor
```

Then, use in Jinja template, as below:

```
{{ CustomURLProcessor().url_for(request, 'decline_event_invite').include_query_params(event_invite=invite.id, sender=invite.sender) }}
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633588/17865804) for a complete working example. Also, this feature might be introduced into the next version of Starlette [#1385](https://github.com/encode/starlette/pull/1385). Thus, you may want to keep an eye on it.

## More options on how to make a class accessible from Jinja templates

Alternative options to make `CustomURLProcessor` class accessible from Jinja templates, in case `templates.env.globals['CustomURLProcessor'] = CustomURLProcessor` didn't work for you, throwing the following error: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'CustomURLProcessor' is undefined`.

**Option 1**

```
templates.env.globals.update(CustomURLProcessor=CustomURLProcessor)
```

**Option 2**

```
import helpers.utils
templates.env.globals['CustomURLProcessor'] = helpers.utils.CustomURLProcessor
# or, equivalently 
templates.env.globals.update(CustomURLProcessor=helpers.utils.CustomURLProcessor)
```

You could even add the whole module, and use in Jinja template like this `helpers.CustomURLProcessor().url_for(request...`.

```
import helpers.utils
templates.env.globals['helpers'] = helpers.utils
```

**Option 3**

The last option would be to pass it as part of your `TemplateResponse`.

```
return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html",  {"request": request, "CustomURLProcessor": CustomURLProcessor})
```

If none of the above worked, perhaps other options described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2) might help, or the problem likely lies elsewhere.

## Update 1 - About including query params

Regarding sending query parameters from a Jinja template, you can now use Starlette's [`starlette.datastructures.URL`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L21), which provides an [`include_query_params`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L141) method.

To use, import the `URL` class and make it accessible from Jinja2 templates:

```py
from starlette.datastructures import URL

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
templates.env.globals['URL'] = URL
```

Then, use in Jinja template as shown below:

```
{{ URL(url_for('decline_event_invite')).include_query_params(event_invite=invite.id, sender=invite.sender) }}
```

## Update 2 - About including query params

The [`request.url_for()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/requests.py#L174) function now returns a [`starlette.datastructures.URL`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L21) object. Hence, you could simply use the below, without needing to import the `URL` class in Jinja2 templates:

```
{{ url_for('decline_event_invite').include_query_params(event_invite=invite.id, sender=invite.sender) }}
```

Comment: Where should CustomURLProcessor be added to the template? I'm trying to add to the same file as the `decline_event_invite` function. At the beginning of it is defined `templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")` and then I add the  `templates.env.globals['CustomURLProcessor'] = CustomURLProcessor` but got `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'CustomURLProcessor' is undefined`

Comment: strange, I did the same as in the link but got the same result.

Comment: I've updated the question. In `event.py` I declare the `templates` variable again, as the other routers in this module use `templates.TemplateResponse`. Could this be the problem?

Comment: adding `CustomURLProcessor`  to the global env in `events.py`  same way as in `main.py` but same get  error. But I think the answer to the question I asked has been answered. I'll look into it.

Comment: I try both method with import and with setup  in the events. py

Comment: As I suspected, the problem was in the structure of my code. It worked the first way, I think all the other options work too. Great hack for passing qwery parameters, thanks for the help