# How to pass Python's time function to Jinja2 template using FastAPI?

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I send a `time.time()` variable `t0` to my template from FastAPI, which is the time update was triggered:

```py
return templates.TemplateResponse("jobs.html", {
   "request": request, "jobs": sorted(out, key=lambda d: d['id'], reverse=True),
   "project_ids": ','.join([str(id) for id in myids]),
   "sorted_collumn": 'id',
   "filter": filter,
   "alljobs":alljobs,
   "nrecent": nrecent,
   "t0": t0
})
```

How can I time it at the end of rendering aka:

`f"processtime:{time.time()-t0:.2f}sec"`

```
time: {{ import time; time.time()-t0 }} 
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'time'
```

or

```
time: {{ time.time()-t0 }}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'float object' has no attribute 'time'
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) helpful, which uses an `APIRoute` class to measure the time taken to process a request.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of Starlette (i.e., [startlette/templating.py](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/88e9fc1411f6bd79131afa4a7d2f4dc576c8bf04/starlette/templating.py#L80))

You can see the following line:
`env.globals["url_for"] = url_for` in:

So adding the line:

```
templates.env.globals["now"] = time.time
```

before the return template above fixes it, and adding the below to `jobs.html` template:

```
time: {{ "{0:0.2f}".format(now()-t0) }} sec
time: 16.01 sec
```

Comment: Similar approach has also been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068465/17865804) to make classes/functions accessible from Jinja2 templates, when one needs to specify _query_, not only _path_, parameters in the `url_for()` function (may prove helpful to anyone who's facing similar issues).